# CSS style from bootswatch is not working on Shiny R

Tags: css, shiny

I want to change the style of my Shiny app. I went here https://bootswatch.com/solar/ and downloaded the style .css `file`: "Solar A spin on Solarized".

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel(tags$i(h1(strong("My Panel Title"),style = "font-family: 'times'; font-size: 82px"))),align="center",    
    navbarPage(theme="bootstrap.min.css",title = 'Methods',
               tabPanel('One'),
               tabPanel('Two'),
               tabPanel('Three'),
               tabPanel('Four'))
)    

server <- function(input, output) {    

}   

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But as you can see the navigation bar looks weird:

[image: nav bar with oversized title and small stacked links]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The theme that you link to is a Bootstrap 4 theme, but [Shiny uses Bootstrap 3](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny#bootstrap-3-migration). For compatible Bootswatch themes, see their v3 collection: https://bootswatch.com/3/.

For example, using the v3 Flatly theme via a CDN:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(tags$i(
    h1(strong("My Panel Title"), style = "font-family: 'times'; font-size: 82px")
  )),
  align = "center",
  navbarPage(
    theme = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.4.1/flatly/bootstrap.min.css",
    title = 'Methods',
    tabPanel('One'),
    tabPanel('Two'),
    tabPanel('Three'),
    tabPanel('Four')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]